# Unable to return html content on REST API build with flask-restful

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, flask-restful

```
Absent<br>\r\n\t\t\tW - Withheld\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t<b>Note:</b><br>\r\n\t\t\tThis Sheet is for general idea of marks you secured. This is not for official use. If any mistakes appear; record at NEB ledger will be referred.\r\n\t\t\r\n\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\r\n \t\t\r\n    </br></br></br></br></br></td>\n</tr>\n</table> is not JSON serializable
```

This is the exact error  I get when trying to access the handle passing all the values. The html content that can be seen there are what I exactly need.I have copied only few sections of it since it was large tags with table and rows. I was able to successfully to load this in web application but here I am working with API.

**is not JSON serializable**

I am scraping a site and from the site I am getting the html table content and trying to return that via my REST API build with flask-restful

marks=requests.post("somesitelinkhere",data=data_load2)

```
soup2=BeautifulSoup(marks.content,'html.parser')
#this is the heading to show what Result it is
headinghere=soup2.find('h2').text
markstable=soup2.find('table')

return {'marksheet':markstable}
```

Consider the above code I have successfully scraped the content and which in available in markstable variable.Now how do I return it  so that it will be accessible when trying to access with the specific handle. What do I have to do to make it serializable or what is the best way to return such content in REST API.

Answer (score 0):

`markstable` is a `BeautifulSoup.Tag` object. You can extract the content string from it using `markstable.contents` and send it over as the response.